# ValueError('need at least one array to stack')

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, valueerror, pytorch-dataloader

When I Processed video and its audio，I encountered an error:

```
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yzx/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 202, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/yzx/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/yzx/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in 
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/yzx/lunwen/PseudoBinaural_CVPR2021-master/data/Augment_dataset.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    data_ret, data_ret_sep = self._get_pseudo_item(index)
  File "/home/yzx/lunwen/PseudoBinaural_CVPR2021-master/data/Pseudo_dataset.py", line 263, in _get_pseudo_item
    stereo = self.construct_stereo_ambi(pst_sources)
  File "/home/yzx/lunwen/PseudoBinaural_CVPR2021-master/data/Pseudo_dataset.py", line 120, in construct_stereo_ambi
    signals = np.stack([src.signal for src in pst_sources], axis=1) # signals shape: [Len, n_signals]
  File "", line 5, in stack
  File "/home/yzx/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 423, in stack
    raise ValueError('need at least one array to stack')
ValueError: need at least one array to stack
```

The list_samlple_file below is the content of train.txt. Every line has the same form as the first line "/home/yzx/lunwen/datasets/FAIR-PLAY/binaural_audios/000383.wav,/home/yzx/lunwen/datasets/FAIR-PLAY/frames/000383". The former path is the path of each audio,and the latter is the folder of the frames of each video.I extracted 10 frames per second in each 10 seconds video.They are splited to 'audio_file' and 'img_folder' in Psedo_dataset.py.I checked this path is true.But I don't know why the error generate.I need your help.

The content of clss Augment_dataset.py is:

```
class AugmentDataset(StereoDataset, PseudoDataset):
    def __init__(self, opt, list_sample_file):
        self.opt = opt
        PseudoDataset.__init__(self, opt, list_sample_file)
        StereoDataset.__init__(self, opt)

        if "MUSIC" in self.opt.datalist:
            dup_times = 1 
            print("dup_times:", dup_times)
        else:
            dup_times = 2 
            print("dup_times:", dup_times)
        self.total_samples *= dup_times # in order to align with the length of FAIR-Play dataset

        random.shuffle(self.audios)
        random.shuffle(self.total_samples)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if random.uniform(0,1) < self.opt.pseudo_ratio:
            data_ret, data_ret_sep = self._get_pseudo_item(index)
        else:
            data_ret = self._get_stereo_item(index)
            _, data_ret_sep = self._get_pseudo_item(index)
        data_ret.update(data_ret_sep)

        return data_ret

    def __len__(self):
        return min(len(self.audios), len(self.total_samples))

    def name(self):
        return 'AugmentDataset'
```

The content of Psedo_dataset.py is:

```
def audio_normalize(samples, desired_rms = 0.1, eps = 1e-4):
    rms = np.maximum(eps, np.sqrt(np.mean(samples**2)))
    samples = samples * (desired_rms / rms)
    return rms / desired_rms, samples

def generate_spectrogram(audio):
    spectro = librosa.core.stft(audio, n_fft=512, hop_length=160, win_length=400, center=True)
    real = np.expand_dims(np.real(spectro), axis=0)
    imag = np.expand_dims(np.imag(spectro), axis=0)
    spectro_two_channel = np.concatenate((real, imag), axis=0)
    return spectro_two_channel

def process_image(image, augment, square=False):
    if square:
        iH, iW = 240, 240
        H, W = 224, 224
    else:
        iH, iW = 240, 480
        H, W = 224, 448
    image = mmcv.imresize(image, (iW,iH))
    h,w,_ = image.shape
    w_offset = w - W 
    h_offset = h - H 
    left = random.randrange(0, w_offset + 1)
    upper = random.randrange(0, h_offset + 1)
    image = mmcv.imcrop(image, np.array([left, upper, left+W-1, upper+H-1]))

    if augment:
        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(Image.fromarray(image))
        image = enhancer.enhance(random.random()*0.6 + 0.7)
        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Color(image)
        image = enhancer.enhance(random.random()*0.6 + 0.7)
    return image

class PseudoDataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, opt, list_sample_file):
        super().__init__()

        self.opt = opt
        self.total_samples = mmcv.list_from_file(list_sample_file)

        normalize = transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
        std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
        )
        vision_transform_list = [transforms.ToTensor(), normalize]
        self.vision_transform = transforms.Compose(vision_transform_list)

        random.seed(self.opt.seed)

        # load background, just one large-sizeimage
        self.bkg_img = mmcv.imread('./data/bkg.png')

        # build binauralizer
        hrtf_dir = "./data/subject03" 
        # binauralizer = SourceBinauralizer(use_hrtfs=True, cipic_dir=hrtf_dir)
        self.hrir_db = CIPIC_HRIR(hrtf_dir)
        # encode to ambisonics, and then stereo
        speakers_phi = (2. * np.arange(2*4) / float(2*4) - 1.) * np.pi
        self.speakers_pos = [Position(phi, 0, 1, 'polar') for phi in speakers_phi]
        self.sph_mat = spherical_harmonics_matrix(self.speakers_pos, max_order=1) # shape: [N_array_speakers, 4]

        # parameter of loading audio 
        self.exp_audio_len = int(self.opt.audio_length * self.opt.audio_sampling_rate)
        #print("Now load {} box info".format(self.opt.mode))
        #self.box_info = mmcv.load('./dataset/ASMR/scripts/results/{}_box_info.pkl'.format(self.opt.mode))

        if opt.fov == '1/3':
            self.fov = 1/3.
        elif opt.fov == '1/2':
            self.fov = 1/2.
        elif opt.fov == '5/6':
            self.fov = 5/6.
        elif opt.fov == '1':
            self.fov = 1. 
        else:
            self.fov = 2/3.

        #self.categories = ['acoustic_guitar', 'banjo', 'bass', 'cello', 'drum', 'harp', 'piano', 'trumpet', 'ukelele']

    def construct_stereo_direct(self, pst_sources):
        stereo = np.zeros((2, self.exp_audio_len))
        for src in pst_sources:
            left_hrir, right_hrir = self.hrir_db.get_closest(src.position)[1:]
            left_signal = np.convolve(src.signal, np.flip(left_hrir, axis=0), 'valid')
            right_signal = np.convolve(src.signal, np.flip(right_hrir, axis=0), 'valid')

            n_valid, i_start = left_signal.shape[0], left_hrir.shape[0] - 1
            stereo[0, i_start:(i_start + n_valid)] += left_signal
            stereo[1, i_start:(i_start + n_valid)] += right_signal

        return stereo

    def construct_stereo_ambi(self, pst_sources):
        # encode to ambisonics
        Y = spherical_harmonics_matrix([src.position for src in pst_sources], max_order=1) # Y shape: [n_signals, 4] 
        signals = np.stack([src.signal for src in pst_sources], axis=1) # signals shape: [Len, n_signals]
        ambisonic = np.dot(signals, Y) # shape: [Len, 4]

        array_speakers_sound = np.dot(ambisonic, self.sph_mat.T)
        #array_speakers_sound = np.dot(ambisonic, np.linalg.pinv(self.sph_mat))
        array_sources = [PositionalSource(array_speakers_sound[:, i], speaker_pos, \
            self.opt.audio_sampling_rate) for i, speaker_pos in enumerate(self.speakers_pos)]

        return self.construct_stereo_direct(array_sources)

    def construct_stereo_ambi_direct(self, pst_sources):
        # encode to ambisonics
        Y = spherical_harmonics_matrix([src.position for src in pst_sources], max_order=1) 
        signals = np.stack([src.signal for src in pst_sources], axis=1)
        ambisonic = np.dot(signals, Y) # shape: [Len, 4]

        stereo = np.stack((
            ambisonic[:, 0] / 2 + ambisonic[:, 1] / 2,
            ambisonic[:, 0] / 2 - ambisonic[:, 1] / 2
        ))

        return stereo

    def _get_pseudo_item(self, index):        
        # ensure the number of audios in a scene
        N = np.random.choice([1,2,3], p=[0.4, 0.5, 0.1])
        chosen_samples = [self.total_samples[index]]
        # avoid repeat sample
        for _ in range(1, N):
            while True:
                new_sample = random.choice(self.total_samples)
                if new_sample not in chosen_samples:
                    chosen_samples.append(new_sample)
                    break

        audio_margin = 0
        init_H = 360
        init_W = 640
        pst_sources = []

        if self.opt.not_use_background:
            cur_bkg_img = np.zeros((init_H, init_W, 3)).astype(np.uint8) 
        else:
            # crop background img, exp_shape: [init_H, init_W, 3]
            bkg_start_x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=self.bkg_img.shape[1] - init_W)
            bkg_start_y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=self.bkg_img.shape[0] - init_H)
            cur_bkg_img = mmcv.imcrop(self.bkg_img.copy(), 
                np.array([bkg_start_x, bkg_start_y, bkg_start_x+init_W-1, bkg_start_y+init_H-1]))
            #H_bkg, W_bkg, _ = cur_bkg_img.shape

        corner_record = []
        patch_size_record = []
        center_x_record = []
        audio_list = []
        patch_list = []
        actual_N = 0
        #load audio
        for idx, chosen_sample in enumerate(chosen_samples):
            audio_file, img_folder = chosen_sample.split(',')
            # audio part
            audio, audio_rate = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=self.opt.audio_sampling_rate, mono=True)
            #randomly get a start time for the audio segment from the original clip
            audio_len = len(audio) / audio_rate
            assert audio_len - self.opt.audio_length - audio_margin > audio_margin
            audio_start_time = random.uniform(audio_margin, audio_len - self.opt.audio_length - audio_margin)
            audio_end_time = audio_start_time + self.opt.audio_length
            audio_start = int(audio_start_time * self.opt.audio_sampling_rate)
            audio_end = audio_start + self.exp_audio_len
            audio = audio[audio_start:audio_end]
            if self.opt.audio_normal:
                normalizer0, audio = audio_normalize(audio)

            # video part
            # load img **patches**, copy bkg_img and construct a new image
            # load accurate frame
            cur_img_list = natsort.natsorted(glob(osp.join(img_folder, '*.jpg')))
            # get the closest frame to the audio segment
            frame_idx = (audio_start_time + audio_end_time) / 2 * 10
            frame_idx = int(np.clip(frame_idx, 0, len(cur_img_list) - 1))
            img_file = cur_img_list[frame_idx]
            img_patch = mmcv.imread(img_file)

            if self.opt.patch_resize:
                h_patch, w_patch, _= img_patch.shape
                resize_ratio = min(1/normalizer0, init_H / h_patch, init_W / 2 / w_patch) 
                img_patch = mmcv.imrescale(img_patch, resize_ratio * random.uniform(0.8, 1))
            H_new, W_new, _ = img_patch.shape

            # just consider the overlap in the horizontal axis
            occupy_matrix = np.ones((init_W))
            # avoid cross border in x dim
            occupy_matrix[:(-W_new + 1)] = 0
            # avoid overlap
            for last_corner_x, W_last in zip(corner_record, patch_size_record):
                occupy_x = max(0, last_corner_x - W_new)
                occupy_matrix[occupy_x : last_corner_x + W_last] = 1

            # random sample position for this mono audio
            free_x_positions = np.where(occupy_matrix == 0)[0]
            if len(free_x_positions) < 2:
                break
            actual_N += 1
            corner_x = random.choice(free_x_positions)
            corner_record.append(corner_x)
            patch_size_record.append(W_new)
            corner_y = random.randint(0, init_H - H_new)
            
            center_y = corner_y + H_new // 2
            center_x = corner_x + W_new // 2
            center_x_record.append(center_x)
            azimuth = (init_W // 2 - center_x) / init_W * pi * self.fov
            elevation = (init_H // 2 - center_y) / init_H * pi / 2

            if self.opt.visualize_data:
                output_dir = 'others/dataset_visual/{:d}_{:d}'.format(N, index)
                if not osp.exists(output_dir):
                    os.mkdir(output_dir)
                if librosa.__version__ >= '0.8.0':
                    import soundfile as sf
                    sf.write(osp.join(output_dir, '{:d}.wav'.format(idx)), audio.transpose(), audio_rate)
                else:
                    librosa.output.write_wav(osp.join(output_dir, '{:d}.wav'.format(idx)), audio, sr=audio_rate)
            audio_list.append(audio)
            patch_list.append(img_file)
            pst_sources.append(PositionalSource(audio, Position(azimuth, elevation, 3, 'polar'), audio_rate))
            pdb.set_trace()

            if self.opt.blending:
                center = (center_x, center_y)
                mask = 255 * np.ones(img_patch.shape, img_patch.dtype)
                cur_bkg_img = cv2.seamlessClone(img_patch, cur_bkg_img, mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
            else:
                patch_in_start_x = corner_x 
                patch_in_start_y = corner_y
                assert patch_in_start_x >= 0
                assert patch_in_start_y >= 0
                cur_bkg_img[patch_in_start_y : patch_in_start_y + H_new, patch_in_start_x : patch_in_start_x + W_new] = img_patch

        if self.opt.stereo_mode == 'direct':
            #print("use direct")
            stereo = self.construct_stereo_direct(pst_sources)
        elif self.opt.stereo_mode == 'ambisonic':
            #print("use ambisonic")
            stereo = self.construct_stereo_ambi(pst_sources)
        elif self.opt.stereo_mode == 'ambidirect':
            #print("use ambidirect")
            stereo = self.construct_stereo_ambi_direct(pst_sources)
        else:
            raise ValueError("please choose right stereo mode")

        normalizer, _ = audio_normalize(stereo[0] + stereo[1])
        stereo = stereo / normalizer
        audio_channel1, audio_channel2 = stereo
        frame = cur_bkg_img
        if self.opt.visualize_data:
            output_dir = 'others/dataset_visual/{:d}_{:d}'.format(N, index)
            if librosa.__version__ >= '0.8.0':
                import soundfile as sf
                sf.write(osp.join(output_dir, 'input_binaural.wav'), stereo.transpose(), audio_rate)
            else:
                librosa.output.write_wav(osp.join(output_dir, 'input_binaural.wav'), stereo, sr=audio_rate)
            mmcv.imwrite(frame, osp.join(output_dir, 'reference.jpg'))
        frame = process_image(frame, self.opt.enable_data_augmentation)
        frame = self.vision_transform(frame)

        #passing the spectrogram of the difference
        audio_diff_spec = torch.FloatTensor(generate_spectrogram(audio_channel1 - audio_channel2))
        audio_mix_spec = torch.FloatTensor(generate_spectrogram(audio_channel1 + audio_channel2))
        
        data_ret = {'frame': frame, 'audio_diff_spec':audio_diff_spec, 'audio_mix_spec':audio_mix_spec}

        # incorporate separation part
        assert len(patch_list) == len(audio_list)
        left_channel = np.zeros(self.exp_audio_len).astype(np.float32)
        right_channel = np.zeros(self.exp_audio_len).astype(np.float32)
        if len(audio_list) >= 2:
            for cur_audio, center_x in zip(audio_list, center_x_record):
                if center_x < init_W // 3:
                    left_channel += cur_audio
                elif center_x > init_W // 3:
                    right_channel += cur_audio
                else:
                    left_channel += cur_audio
                    right_channel += cur_audio
                
            _, left_channel = audio_normalize(left_channel)
            _, right_channel = audio_normalize(right_channel)
        else:
            left_channel = audio_channel1
            right_channel = audio_channel2

        if self.opt.visualize_data:
            output_dir = 'others/dataset_visual/{:d}_{:d}'.format(N, index)
            if librosa.__version__ >= '0.8.0':
                import soundfile as sf
                sf.write(osp.join(output_dir, 'gt_left.wav'), left_channel, audio_rate)
                sf.write(osp.join(output_dir, 'gt_right.wav'), right_channel, audio_rate)
            else:
                librosa.output.write_wav(osp.join(output_dir, 'gt_left.wav'), left_channel, audio_rate)
                librosa.output.write_wav(osp.join(output_dir, 'gt_right.wav'), right_channel, audio_rate)

        sep_mix_spec = audio_mix_spec
        sep_diff_spec = torch.FloatTensor(generate_spectrogram(left_channel - right_channel))
        frame_sep_list = frame

        if self.opt.mode == 'train':
            data_ret_sep = {'frame_sep': frame_sep_list, 'sep_diff_spec': sep_diff_spec, 'sep_mix_spec': sep_mix_spec}
        else:
            data_ret_sep = {'frame_sep': frame_sep_list, 'sep_diff_spec': sep_diff_spec, 'sep_mix_spec': sep_mix_spec, 'left_audio': left_channel, 'right_audio': right_channel}

        return data_ret, data_ret_sep

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        data_ret, data_ret_sep = self._get_pseudo_item(index)
        if self.opt.dataset_mode == 'Pseudo_stereo':
            return data_ret
        elif self.opt.dataset_mode == 'Pseudo_sep':
            return data_ret_sep
        else:
            data_ret.update(data_ret_sep)
            return data_ret

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.total_samples)

    def name(self):
        return 'PseudoDataset'

    def initialize(self, opt):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```py
signals = np.stack([src.signal for src in pst_sources], axis=1) # signals shape: [Len, n_signals]
```

It looks like `pst_sources` is empty, and so you are trying to stack an empty list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes,I know the error is here.But I don't know why. I choose the the first line of ```list_samlple_file ``` to call these modules,it is no problem. But the error is always here when running.